# How to authorise a web app written in plain Javascript to talk to Google AutoML Prediction Model Restful API?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, restful-authentication

There seems to be a lot of documentation lying around everywhere about how to use Google Cloud Platform and its fancy AutoML service. But I couldn't find anything that is solving my problem of trying to get a prediction from a trained model on AutoML via a local website. The website code is in this link: https://pastebin.com/xsfkYf6C

All I get in return from uploading an image and clicking "process" button on this site is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

I surely have made some mistakes somewhere, but I'm completely clueless as to how I would fix this or maybe because I'm just too dumb to figure it out yet. My research has yielded none to very little results. This article might be of some help to clear things up about AutoML Restful API: https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.models/predict

Appreciate any of your suggestions and code fixes.
Thanks so much and have a great day!

Comment: Have you found the API call solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your api key to REST API call like this:

```
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/a...1/locations/us-central1/models/ICN...1:predict?key=API_KEY
```

To create an API key you need a Google Cloud account since it's only free up to a certain point and then you will get charged for.

Therefore you should secure this key and make sure it is not visible publicly(so don't put in your html source code, backend should handle this call).

More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys)

Comment: I already tried to create API Key and append in the URL for post request, but still get the same error 401.

Answer (score 0):

The error could mean that you are using an API Key or the token you provided is wrong/malformed. I think that creating a token using Playground, ServerSide, Javascript, etc. will fail due to there are not OAuth2.0 scopes for AutoML, maybe because is still in beta release.

Keeping in mind that a token generated from gcloud it works, I can suggest generating programmatically a token [impersonating a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-direct) to [generate the token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth), [this example](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-serviceaccountactor-iam-role-for-account-impersonation-on-google-cloud-platform-a9e7118480ed) contains all the pieces of the puzzle. This means that your user could generate a service account token on behalf of your service

Points to consider when executing the code:

1. Enable the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API.
2. Update the code according to your own configuration, project and json file.
3. Use the generic scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform as the jwt_scope.

IMPORTANT: The python code it is using urllib and httplib, which means that it could be translated to a POST requests with some extra effort (to be used in your javascript)

Let us know if it works for your specific use case!